# php not working on AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Its my first time using a ubuntu server, and also my first time using a cloud server.

My question is that I've installed apache2, mysql, php5 on my ubuntu(I know that there is a RDS system at AWS but I'm trying it for sake of practice)

well my mysql and phpmyadmin works just right but php ain't....

I made an easy php page with a line of echo in it but it shows 404 not found....
//
Not Found

The requested URL /phpinfo.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at (IPaddress) Port 80
//
First, I don't know where the root directory is..(I've searched on the web that it is /var/www/  is this true?)

Second, I used #vi /var/www/logintest.php and saved it with :wq,, is this 'vi' something similar to text editor in Windows? Are there any file format or encoding issues?

Third, I allocated a public IP to my EC2 server, but the putty client shows another ip... it starts with root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/home/ubuntu#  what is this xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx??

Sorry for such tiny questions.. It's my first time with Ubuntu

Comment: Is there a /var/www/html folder? If so, that's likely your actual webroot.

"what is this xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx??" - That's the internal hostname auto generated from the internal IP address.

Comment: oh is it /var/www/html ?? I thought it was var/www

Comment: and when I tyoe $sudo su, the terminal says root-ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx and it is not the same as one I allocated at the AWS console...

Comment: wooh.. the root directory was /var/www/html/ thx lol